# SPLIT A STRING THEN CHANGE IT TO DECIMAL AND MULTIPLY IT TO A VALUE IN ANOTHER TABLE

Tags: sql-server, case

I need to separate from Table 1, Col1 that contains 'currency' and 'value' or ';'.

```
Table1

Col1      
GBP;185.00   
EUR;152.46   
;                         
SEK;364.55    
USD;364.55
```

Then in Table 2 I use 'CurrCode' to join with 'Value' from Table1.

```
Table2

CurrValue   CurrCode
   11.01    GBP
    NULL    EUR
            ---
    9.44    SEK
    9.01    USD
```

I build this code but the amount of data is too big, It works only until 9000 columns and then crashes. Is there a way to work this around?

```
SELECT 
  Col1
 ,(reverse(substring(reverse(Col1),0,charindex(';',reverse(Col1))))) as LocalValue
 ,c.currVALUE
 ,substring(Col1,1,charindex(';',Col1)-1) as Currency
 ,case when Col1 like 'EUR;%' then  (reverse(substring(reverse(Col1),0,charindex(';',reverse(Col1)))))
         else try_convert(numeric(18,5),(reverse(substring(reverse(Col1),0, 
  charindex(';',reverse(Col1))))))* c.CurrValue 
         end as ValueEUR
 from b
 left join c
 on c.CurrencyCode = substring(Col1,1,charindex(';',Col1)-1)
```

The desired result is a table that shows CurrValue, Currecy and ValueEUR (where 'CurrValue' * 'Localvalue' = 'ValueEUR'):

```
  LocalValue    Currency    ValueEUR
  185.33        GBP         2040.48
  152.46        EUR         152.46
  0             ---         0
  364.55        SEK         3441.35
  364.55        USD         3284.60
```

NOTE: When Currency is EUR, CurrValue is NULL and ValueEUR is the same as LocalValue.

Comment: A better solution would be to normalize your database. Use one table to store possible currencies, one table to store conversion values, and one table to store sums. Then it just becomes a trivial join query to get your desired results.

Comment: The workaround is to fix the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a CTE vTable1 for demo only. I think it's better for you to create a view.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table2

create table #Table1
(
    Col1 varchar(100)
)

create table #Table2
(
    CurrValue decimal(18,2),
    CurrCode varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO #Table1 
values
('GBP;185.00'),
('EUR;152.46'),
(';'),
('DKK;364.55'),
('SEK;364.55'),
('USD;364.55')

INSERT INTO #Table2
VALUES
(11.01, 'GBP'),
(null,  'EUR'),
(null,  '---'),
(9.44,  'SEK'),
(9.01,  'USD')

;WITH vTable1 (Currency, Value)
as
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1,0,CHARINDEX(';',Col1)) AS Currency
          ,TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUBSTRING(Col1,CHARINDEX(';',Col1)+1, LEN(Col1))) as Value
    FROM #Table1
)

SELECT COALESCE(t1.Value, 0) as CurrValue
      ,t2.CurrCode as Currency
      ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), COALESCE(t2.CurrValue * t1.Value, t1.Value, 0)) AS ValueEUR
FROM vTable1 as t1 
    RIGHT JOIN #Table2 as t2
        on t1.Currency = t2.CurrCode
```

Comment: That solution works for less than 10000 rows. After that it shows an error: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: I have updated the answer and added the `TRY_CONVERT` on the CTE vTable1. I think you have on Table1 some values  like this `USD;nonumeric`

Comment: I looked for nonnumeric values and didn't find any. I was about to create a view when using COALESCE for eliminating null values, that I found a solution. Thanks for your help and time Max.

Comment: Glad to help you, if my answer is correct, please mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that solved it:

```
SELECT 
    t.Col1
    ,COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,3),SUBSTRING(t.Col1,CHARINDEX(';',t.Col1)+1, 
 LEN(t.Col1))),0) AS LocalValue
    ,COALESCE(c.CurrValue,0) as CurrValue
    ,SUBSTRING (t.Col1, 0, CHARINDEX(';',t.Col1)) AS Currency
,COALESCE((c.CurrValue*TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,3),SUBSTRING(t.Col1,CHARINDEX(';',t.Col1)+1,LEN(t.Col1)))),COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,3),SUBSTRING(t.Col1,CHARINDEX(';',t. 
Col1)+1, LEN(t.Col1))),0)) AS ValueEUR

from Table1 as t
left join Table1 as c
on c.CurrCode = SUBSTRING (Col1, 0, CHARINDEX(';',Col1))
```